# JMEter gives strange results

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter for load testing.Because I want to simulate 200 users on a specific link: catalogus. I have the site now local. So the URL of the local site is: http://verploegenbalie.nl/product-catalog. But for testing I just use now 2 users. what also in the image is displaying. But the strange thing is, that if I dont check the: 
-Follow Redirects option and
- Use Keep Alive option. then the link is not working. In the tree it becomes red and appears as: `GET http://verploegenbalie.nl/product-catalog/product-catalog` what is wrong, because it has to be:`http://verploegenbalie.nl/product-catalog`

But if I uncheck the two options. I get strange results.I get as output more then two responses. And If I look at the tab: Response Data I see: Object moved to here.

I make it clear with a couple of screenshots.

Thank you[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I do like this:

[image]

Then I will get by request this results:

GET http://product-catalog/

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive

What ofcourse is not the correct URL.

Yes. If I do it like this:
[image]

Then the correct urls will be returned. But a other strange thing is that I have two users. You can see it on this image:
[image]

But the output gives by response data" 20 results. Where the number 20 comes from? See image:
[image]

Comment: Is somebody there? Ok

Comment: you need to write a question more clearly. It's unreadable (and not because of English, but because it's not clear which picture belongs to which situation and what actually you perceive as a problem). Also in first part you say "if I dont check the: -Follow Redirects option and - Use Keep Alive option". And then in second part you say "But if I uncheck the two options".

Comment: I edit the post. You see it? So can you explain why it generates 20? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you've put in server name or ip field is wrong.
You've put the full URL while it should only contain the host part of the URL.

So "server name of ip field" mist contain:

- verploegenbalie.nl

"Path" field must contain:

- /product-catalog

Comment: I clarified my answer. If ok you should accept it and upvote

Comment: Ah, thank you. I edit the post. So what is the number 20?

Comment: Hi, this is another question you're asking. As per SO way, please ask a new question I will answer.